# Find average amount of time from Requisition Submitted to Order Created

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `requisition_headers` and `order_headers`. I am interested in finding the average time it takes from the time the requisition is submitted (`requisition_headers.submitted_at`) and the time the order is created (`orders.headers_created_at`) where the `requisition_headers.status <> 'draft'`.

I would like the result to look like:

```
Avg_Req_To_PO_Cycle_Time = 3.2 Days
```

I have the following script but it's not working:

```
SELECT Database() as Customer,
       AVG(timestampdiff(requisition_headers.submitted_at,order_headers.created_at)) AS REQ_PO_Cycle_Time
  FROM order_headers 
  LEFT JOIN requisition_headers ON order_headers.requisition_header_id = requisition_headers.id
 WHERE requisition_headers.status <> 'draft'
```

Any Ideas?

--UPDATE--

I changed the query to the following and now get a response of  229491.71 my question is- is that days, hours, minutes, seconds?

```
SELECT DATABASE() AS CUSTOMER,
AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(order_headers.created_at,requisition_headers.submitted_at))) as Cycle_time
FROM order_headers LEFT JOIN requisition_headers ON order_headers.requisition_header_id = requisition_headers.id
```

where requisition_headers.status <> 'draft'

Comment: Could you show 1) what results you ARE getting and 2) example data?

Comment: What is `SELECT Database()` supposed to do?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: do you have one to one relation amoung tables or something else

Comment: The requisition_header_ID is loaded on the order_headers table. I'm getting errors and not getting any results from my query.The select database() as customer, shows the DB Name which is the customer I'm running it against. I'm bringing this over in order to show what customer this data applies to.

Comment: Each Order is created by one requisitoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you know what a system function returns when you use it. The `TimestampDiff` function returns the difference between the two dates in the unit you specify in the first argument. You don't specify that unit so I don't know what you get back. I get a compile error.

In your second attempt, you are using `TimeDiff` which returns an interval value, then converting the result of `Avg` to seconds. So if you want the result in fractional days just divide by the number of seconds in a day.

You also use a `left join` when getting the dates. At first I thought you wanted to get all the requisitions whether the orders had been created or not. But you are joining the tables in the wrong order for that. But, assuming that is your intention, if the order has not yet been created you will be putting `NULL` as one of the parameters. You will get a `NULL` as an answer so you get nothing. If you want to use a `left join`, then you should specify a substitute date for any missing Created dates -- after getting the table in the right order, that is.

Here are two options. One ignores orders that have not yet been created by using a regular `inner join`. The other includes those but substitutes the current date and time.

By asking for the number of minutes between the dates, the final answer in days is found by dividing by the number of minutes in a day.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b970d/2/0)

```
SELECT  Customer,
        AVG( timestampdiff( minute, r.submitted_at,
             o.created_at)) / (24 * 60 )AS REQ_PO_Cycle_Time
FROM    requisition_headers r
JOIN    order_headers o
    ON  o.requisition_header_id = r.id
WHERE   r.status <> 'draft'
group by Customer;

SELECT  Customer,
        AVG( timestampdiff( minute, r.submitted_at,
             IfNull( o.created_at, CurDate()))) / (24 * 60 )AS REQ_PO_Cycle_Time
FROM    requisition_headers r
LEFT JOIN order_headers o
    ON  o.requisition_header_id = r.id
WHERE   r.status <> 'draft'
group by Customer;
```